# is it possible to use outer select's variable into inner select in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to generate a report that shows all the establishment and the number of students living the specific establishment. (Three Tables - Establishment table, Room table, and Beds table)

This is my model:

```
        public function report_Management(){

          $query="SELECT e.owner, e.id as 'Establishment_ID', e.name, (SELECT COUNT(b.bed_no) FROM beds b, users u, establishment e, room r WHERE r.establishment_id = Establishment_ID) as 'Number Of Ateneans' FROM establishment e GROUP BY e.id";


  return $this->db->query($query);

        }
```

I'm trying to use the e.id as 'Establishment_ID' in the inner Select statement

Comment: How beds relate to establishment ? can you provide proper schema of your tables

Comment: Never mind I solved it.  $query="SELECT e.owner, e.id as 'Establishment_ID2', e.name, (SELECT COUNT(b.bed_no) FROM beds b, registrar u, room r WHERE Establishment_ID2 = r.establishment_id AND r.room_id = b.room_id AND u.id = b.student_id) as 'Number Of Ateneans' FROM establishment e GROUP BY e.id";

Answer (score 0):

$query="SELECT e.owner, e.id as 'Establishment_ID2', e.name, (SELECT COUNT(b.bed_no) FROM beds b, registrar u, room r WHERE Establishment_ID2 = r.establishment_id AND r.room_id = b.room_id AND u.id = b.student_id) as 'Number Of Ateneans' FROM establishment e GROUP BY e.id";